# Appending row to html table with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable

When my data coming from json and i tried to append row for my datatable with this code. But it didn't work. How can i fix this ?

```
<table style="width:300px" >
    <thead>
            <th>
                Name
            </th>


    </thead>
    <tbody id="location">


    </tbody>
</table>
```

---

```
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: "GET",
        url: 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users',
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {

            var trHTML = '';
            for (var i = 1; i > data.length; i++) {
                console.log(data[i].name);
                trHTML += '<tr><td><span>' + data[i].name + '</span></td></tr>';

            };
            $('#location tbody').append(trHTML);


        },

        error: function (msg) {

            alert(msg.responseText);
        }
    });
```

My actual goal is adding row to footable datatable plugin but i can't fix it too.

Comment: Change `$('#location tbody').append(trHTML)` to `$('#location').append(trHTML)`

Comment: in response change i<data.length

Comment: Please explain what "didn't work" means.  Does it throw a Javascript exception?  Does it not draw anything?  Do you see messages in the console?

Comment: i tried but it didn't work. @Azim and Console didn't give any error :S .

Comment: Also follow  Rakshith's comment. @HarunKARATAŞ

Comment: Why would he delete `tr` in `thead`? @CiroCorvino

Comment: Remove the `for` and use `trHTML = data.map(o=>\`<tr><td><span>${o.name}</span></td></tr>\`).join\`\`` instead.

Comment: @Rakshith yes thats my fault thanks. its working correctly.

Comment: @CiroCorvino. No, `<tr>` is obligatory for every row (header row or body row). `<th>` means header cell and `<td>` body cell

Comment: Well, you could suggest to wrap `th` in `tr` then. @CiroCorvino

Comment: Then how can we use `th`? @CiroCorvino

Comment: [See](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_th.asp) @CiroCorvino

Comment: ahahah :) thank you @Azim.. you helped me to learn one html5 lesson on th element.. I always seen used the th element outer tr, and I always thought that because a th element it is alway a single row, but probably you can define multiple tr of th type impacting on the format of the cels.. and so, it is better to wrap th in tr element :)

Comment: @Guedes, I read now your comment, after clarified this point, I'm agree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code. Most are already mentioned in the commennts:

1) Your loop does not work because the condition `i > data.length` is never true. I suggest using `jQuery.each(...)` to loop over data. Or fix it to `i < data.length` but then you also have to start with `var i = 0`.

2) `$('#location tbody')` does not exist in your html. That would be a `tbody` element inside an element with the id `location`. You want `$('tbody#location')` or just `$('#location')` as you should not have multiple items with the same id in your html anyway.

3) Your html inside `thead` is not correct. It will work this way, but it is not clean html.

Hope this list helps. It basically summarises the comments. (Thanks to all you guys here!)

Comment: Note my edit with `var i = 0` in the loop... otherwise you will loose one element of data.